# Having trouble with pointers and strings, gibberish printed

Tags: c, pointers

This is a passphrase (diceware) generator that uses [libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org/).

The get_word function is supposed to write the selected word (string) to the pointer passed as the argument `char *word`, but it's not working. Instead, gibberish - random characters, is printed. You can see this when it prints the *first word*.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sodium.h>

void roll_dice(char *combo) {
    uint32_t dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;
    uint32_t upper = 6;

    dice1 = randombytes_uniform(upper) + 1;
    dice2 = randombytes_uniform(upper) + 1;
    dice3 = randombytes_uniform(upper) + 1;
    dice4 = randombytes_uniform(upper) + 1;
    dice5 = randombytes_uniform(upper) + 1;

    sprintf(combo, "%d%d%d%d%d", dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5);
}

int get_word(char *combo, char *word) {
    FILE *stream;
    char line[20];
    char *wordline;

    stream = fopen("/usr/local/etc/passwiz/eff_large_wordlist.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == stream) {
        printf("Failed to open wordlist\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stream)) {
        wordline = strstr(line, combo);

        if (wordline > 0) {
            // TODO: slice the string to obtain just the word
            //wordline = strtok(wordline, "\t");
            //wordline = strtok(wordline, "\t");

            *word = wordline;
        }
    }

    fclose(stream);
}

int main(void) {
    if (sodium_init() < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    char combo[6];
    roll_dice(combo);
    printf("Dice numbers: %s\n", combo);

    char word1[20];
    char *ptr = &word1;

    if (get_word(combo, ptr) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("First word: %s\n", word1);

    // TODO: get 6 words
}
```

The wordlist I'm using comes from the EFF. See [here](https://www.eff.org/files/2016/07/18/eff_large_wordlist.txt).

```
11111   abacus
11112   abdomen
11113   abdominal
11114   abide
11115   abiding
11116   ability
11121   ablaze
11122   able
11123   abnormal
11124   abrasion
11125   abrasive

up to 66666
```

An example of the standard output I see when I run it:

```
Dice numbers: 32345
First word: 3#@$#
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm getting a lot of warnings from the compiler. The warnings alone did not help me understand what I'm doing wrong - I'm really new to C. I'll post the warnings when I get home.

Comment: Are you not getting any warnings like `warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast`?

Comment: @0___________ what else does `*word = wordline;` do?

Comment: @pmacfarlane it does nothing - it assigns `char` array element  with pointer converted to `char`

Comment: @pmacfarlane Sorry, yes, I see warnings like that. I just don't understand why they happen. I'm new to C. I come from languages like PHP and Python.

Comment: @0___________ Fair enough - that's technically correct. They have issues in this area and should heed the warnings.

Comment: @crimson_king Sure.  Let us know what warnings you still have when you are home.  Another issue is that within your functions, which return data, don't always return a value.  You are not returning a success value if you succeed in get_word().  You also don't return for all failure conditions, such as if your if-statement fails.  main() also doesn't return a value at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is

```
char word1[20];
char *ptr = &word1;
```

It should be

```
char* ptr = word1;
```

Since ptr is pointing to the address of word1, it is going to start overwriting all sorts of data.  Once you've fixed that, the next problem is

```
*word = wordline;
```

The intent is probably to copy the contents of wordline into word so this should be

```
strcpy(word, wordline);
```

If you switch on the compiler warnings, it should tell you about these.

Comment: I missed that on my first skim through.  Really, I don't think OP even needs pointer, ptr.  Probably could just pass word1 directly into getword() and let it decay into a pointer.  I could be wrong and it might generate a warning.  I didn't actually try it.

Comment: No - pointer not needed.  word1 could be passed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty problems.

1. `*word = wordline;`

You assign integer with pointer. Probably you want to modify the pointer passed to the function. You need to declare this parameter as pointer to pointer to achieve it.

```
int get_word(char *combo, char **word)
```

2. Even if you change it. The assigned pointer will reference local array which will stop to exist when function returns.
3. Even if you make the `line` static, you print `word1` which is not modified by assigning the pointer.

The solution:

You need to copy the string to the parameter (keeping its type as `char *`):

instead of `*word = wordline;` -> `strcpy(word, wordline);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the compiler isn't complaining at you for a mismatching type.

Within the function *get_word()* the line:

```
*word = wordline;
```

Is assigning the a type (char*), a pointer, into a type (char) at the location pointed to by pointer word.  I think that you meant:

```
strcpy(word, wordline);
```

Answer (score 1):

As with the other answers and comments, I paid attention to the compiler warnings that were indicating you were attempting to reference a "pointer to a pointer" instead of referencing the character array name, which is effectively the pointer to the array.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/main.c|44|warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/main.c|58|warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/main.c|49|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Reviewing the spirit of the program's intended use, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void roll_dice(char *combo)
{
    int dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;
    int upper = 6;
    time_t t;

    /* Intializes random number generator - using this in lieu of sodium */
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    dice1 = rand() % upper + 1;
    dice2 = rand() % upper + 1;
    dice3 = rand() % upper + 1;
    dice4 = rand() % upper + 1;
    dice5 = rand() % upper + 1;

    sprintf(combo, "%d%d%d%d%d", dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5);
}

int get_word(char *combo, char *word)
{
    FILE *stream;
    char line[20];
    char *wordline;

    stream = fopen("eff_large_wordlist.txt", "r");  /* Placed a copy of the file into the executable file's folder for testing */

    if (NULL == stream)
    {
        printf("Failed to open wordlist\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stream))
    {
        wordline = strstr(line, combo);

        if (wordline != NULL)   /* Copy over the data in local variable wordline to character array pointer "word", starting at the text after the five-digit number */
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 6; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (wordline[i] == '\0')
                    break;
                if (wordline[i] >= ' ' && wordline[i] <= '~')
                {
                    word[j] = wordline[i];
                    j++;
                    word[j] = '\0';
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(stream);

    return 0;   /* Needed this to address compiler warning */
}

int main(void)
{
    char combo[6];
    roll_dice(combo);
    printf("Dice numbers: %s\n", combo);

    char word1[20];

    if (get_word(combo, word1) < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("First word: %s\n", word1);

    // TODO: get 6 words
```

Some points to note:

- The pointer references in the function calls and within the functions were corrected so that character arrays were being referenced properly to address the compiler warnings.
- Only because I do not have the "sodium" library, standard random number generation was used as that appeared to be the rationale for utilizing this library/toolkit; the end result still were proper random digits.
- The "strcpy" function could have been used as was suggested in the prior good comments; however, since the intent was to acquire the word associated with the five-digit random number, a "for" loop was used to parse through the acquired line from the file.
- And, to keep the testing isolated, the text file was placed into the same folder as the executable program just to keep things simple.

With all of that, following were output data at the terminal for some tests.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/bin/Release$ ./Sodium 
Dice numbers: 66233
First word: waving
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/bin/Release$ ./Sodium 
Dice numbers: 33253
First word: haggler
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/bin/Release$ ./Sodium 
Dice numbers: 66251
First word: whinny
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Sodium/bin/Release$ ./Sodium 
Dice numbers: 66251
First word: whinny
```

So, be cognizant of how pointer referencing is utilized with character arrays.  You may want to do some further tutorial study on this concept.

Comment: More idiomatic to move `srand((unsigned) time(&t));` outside of re-callable functions like `roll_dice()` and into `main()` - which is only uncommonly called more than once.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer, it was certainly helpful. I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

There's already been lots of feedback about the differences between `char **` and `char *` that don't need repeating.

While it seems convenient to open/close a file in the function as many times as needed, this does place a burden on the OS and will slow execution. Further, on average the program will read 1/2 way into the file before finding the marker being sought. Repeating this 6 times (for 6 words) will be like reading the entire file 3 times. Wasteful.

As the file is not large, loading it once in its entirety seems to make sense. Then it can be repeatedly scanned for interesting targets. (This code presumes the last character in the file will be the '\n' at the end of the last word.)

Like @NoDakker, I don't use Sodium, so have devised an alternative method to generate strings of 5 ASCII digits representing 5 rolls of a die.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

// Load file contents to alloc'd memory, preserving end-of-buffer
// return pointer to buffer to be free'd by caller
char *loadFile( char *fname ) {
    struct stat finfo;

    if( stat( fname, &finfo ) != 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot see '%s'\n", fname );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen( fname, "rb" );
    if( !fp ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open '%s'\n", fname );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char *buf = malloc( finfo.st_size + 1 ); // NB: +1
    if( !buf ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Malloc() failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t nread = fread( buf, 1, finfo.st_size, fp );
    if( nread != (size_t)finfo.st_size ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Read incomplete\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose( fp );

    buf[ nread ] = '\0'; // extra byte set to NULL (for str functions)

    return buf;
}

void roll_dice( char *combo ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        *combo++ = '1' + rand() % 6;
    *combo = '\0'; // terminate
}

int main( void ) {
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    char *all = loadFile( "eff_large_wordlist.txt" );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        char combo[ 5 + 1 ];
        roll_dice( combo );
        char *p = strstr( all, combo );
        if( p ) {
            p += 6;
            do putchar( *p ); while( *p++ != '\n' ); // non-destructive output
        }
    }

    free( all );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
prelude
herbal
pennant
cash
empirical
secluded
```

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice and load the file only once.